# I have selected a radio button and I need to double check that its actually selected in the Robot framework

Tags: radio-button, robotframework

My page is having multiple Radio buttons and I have selected one of them. Now I need to double check whether its actually got selected and if its True I would like to drive my flow accordingly. Here is how I tried using the Robot Framework

```
Click Element    //*[text()=' Small' ] //*[@name='size']

Radio Button Should Be Set To    xpath=(//*[text()=' Small' ] //*[@name='size'])    true
```

I am not sure about the things I specified in the second line. Is this correct

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
Radio Button Should Be Set To    size    true
```

The argument to provide to `Radio Button Should Be Set To` is not an xpath or other locator, but the group's name.
What the framework does with the argument is to substitute it in this xpath:

```
xpath://input[@type='radio' and @name='%s']
```

, get all matching elements, iterate thorough them to find the selected one and assert - case sensitively! - its value is the same as your second argument.

And now you see why your call failed - having provided a full xpath, after the substitution it ended up as invalid/not matched expression and the keyword failed.